# IIS: set response code in web.config

Tags: iis, web-config

I have a tiny website that serves as my maintenance placeholder page.

It has one html document that gets served as an error page for 404s and 403s which will, since there's nothing else there, be always served.

But really, I wish the response code was rather something like 503. How can I do that purely in web.config without resorting to ASP.NET?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" >
         <remove statusCode="500" />
         <error statusCode="500"
            prefixLanguageFilePath="C:\Contoso\Content\errors"
            path="500.htm" />
       </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534918/iis-set-response-code-in-web-config) for more info:

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with my question. You're just setting the error page for a 500. Also you're just linking this question.